# how to expand vertical scroll after slideDown?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

 // hides the slickbox as soon as the DOM is ready
  $('#content').hide();

 // toggles the content when you click the right link  
  $('#togglebutton').click(function() {
    if ( $(this).hasClass("active"))
    {
        $('#content').slideDown(200);
        $(this).removeClass("active");
        $("#toggleimg").attr("src", "images/less.png"); //swap the image

    var destination = $("#bottombar").offset().top;
    //alert(destination);
    //$("html,body").animate({ scrollTop: destination},"slow");
    $('html, body').delay('200').animate({
    scrollTop: $('#bottombar').offset().top + 111
    }, 200);



    } else {
        $(this).addClass("active");
        $("#toggleimg").attr("src", "images/more.png"); //swap the image
        $('#content').slideUp(200);
    }
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
  });
});
```

You can see it in action here www.graysonearle.com/Lumarca
I've tried for hours to get this to work...
I just want the browser window to allow the user to scroll after the div has slid down.